# switchMap cancel options http request in ngrx effect

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I have a ngrx effect like this one:

```
@Effect()
  throwError$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<notificationActions.ErrorThrow>(
      notificationActions.ActionTypes.ThrowError
    ),
    tap(() => {
      this.store.dispatch(new masterActions.LoadingHide());
      this.sub = this.devTools.liftedState.subscribe(data => {
        this.errorLogService.addErrorLog(JSON.stringify(data)).subscribe(data2 => console.log('data2', data));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    }),
    map(action => action.payload),
    tap(() => {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }),
    mergeMap(error => {
      return of(
        new notificationActions.ErrorAdd({
          type: error.type,
          description: error.description
        })
      );
    })
  );
```

the addErrorLog method of the errorLogService sends a http post request for storing the error log into a database. Everything is working doing the request like this, first an options request and then the post request, but if I switch to a switchMap to combine both observables the options request gets cancelled when I inspect it on the network tab on chrome dev tools.

This is the part of the code refactorized

```
tap(() => {
      this.store.dispatch(new masterActions.LoadingHide());
      this.sub = this.devTools.liftedState
        .pipe(
          switchMap(data => {
            console.log('data', data);
            return this.errorLogService.addErrorLog(JSON.stringify(data));
          })
        )
        .subscribe();
    })
```

any clues?

Comment: So do you really want to be using `switchMap`? Maybe `concatMap` is what you want?

Comment: it's not working even if I change it to concatMap

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem. Replacing `switchMap` with `mergeMap` did it for me, now each HTTP request waits to complete.

Comment: mergeMap runs your Observables in parallel whereas switchMap cancels the last emit and switches to the new one. This is a great read on this: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/